# OpenVPN/Tunnelblick through wireless router, no connection

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN with Tunneblick on my Macbook Pro to access a server on my job. I't works fine, but i can't get it working with my Netgear WGT624v3 wireless router.

I get this warning:

> WARNING: potential route subnet
>   conflict between local LAN
>   [192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0] and remote
>   VPN [192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0]

Someone told me that i should "port forward" on my router, but i can't figure out the right settings. Also not shure i'm doing it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Tunnelblick google group. And got help, here's the link to the [discussion](http://groups.google.se/group/tunnelblick-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4017478a7c3b91a9).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. The easiest step to troubleshoot, is your OpenVPN server running correctly? Check this by connecting to it while in your LAN. If all is good, then portforwarding has not been properly configured in your router.

Step 2. If you cannot connect whilst in your LAN, your OpenVPN server is not configured correctly.

Go back to step 1.